# Sort tuple by first then second then third

Tags: python

I have the following tuple:

```
[[278, 388, 0.95434654], [279, 388, 0.98770386], [280, 388, 0.960356], [442, 388, 0.98245245], [443, 388, 0.96607447], [278, 389, 0.95714802], [279, 389, 0.98451048], [280, 389, 0.95131117], [442, 389, 0.98007435], [443, 389, 0.95733315]]
```

I would like to sort it by first then second then third.

I tried the following but it only sorts by first:

```
def getKey(item):
    return item[0]

all_matches_tuple = sorted(all_matches_tuple, key=getKey)
```

Comment: Note: Those aren't tuples. Those are lists. You have a list of lists.

Comment: I corrected the spelling of `tuple`, but you really have lists here.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had to have the key word. It is working

Answer (score 2):

Just sort without a key, the default is to sort tuples in lexicographical order:

```
sorted(all_matches_tuple)
```

Demo:

```
>>> sorted([[278, 388, 0.95434654], [279, 388, 0.98770386], [280, 388, 0.960356], [442, 388, 0.98245245], [443, 388, 0.96607447], [278, 389, 0.95714802], [279, 389, 0.98451048], [280, 389, 0.95131117], [442, 389, 0.98007435], [443, 389, 0.95733315]])
[[278, 388, 0.95434654], [278, 389, 0.95714802], [279, 388, 0.98770386], [279, 389, 0.98451048], [280, 388, 0.960356], [280, 389, 0.95131117], [442, 388, 0.98245245], [442, 389, 0.98007435], [443, 388, 0.96607447], [443, 389, 0.95733315]]
```

but note that your sample doesn't actually contain any values where both the first and second number are equal.